# Posting Json data to AWS cloud service using REST webservices

Tags: java, rest, amazon-web-services, post, jersey

I want to post data to a platform on AWS. It accepts data only in Json format. I am not using a rest client(Like Advance Rest Client or Postman) because I can only send a single document at a time.

I want to write a program in java that takes a Json file and posts all the documents in the file to the platform. I understand Rest Web Services but I'm a beginner. I want a loop that takes in a single document and posts it with every iteration. I am not sure where to begin with this program. Please help. Excuse if I missed anything obvious.

PS: I know how to input a json file and convert the data to a document object.

Comment: Read the file and then read the content using FileReader or similar Java API. Iterate over JSONArray and for each JSONObject send it to your AWS Service.

Comment: Yes, but how to send it to the AWS service?

Comment: you can use REST or SOAP Webservice.

Comment: if you have freedom to use some framework then , i would suggest see here : https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Comment: I am acquainted with jersey framework. But how do I set the URL. Connect to the AWS host and run it. Because I can run on a local server(which gives localhost:8080) and set path using @Path, but I want the URL to be (aws.example.com/data/example), where I have to post the data. How?

Comment: Does webservice exist ? if yes then you should know the URL or ask in your team about the URL

Comment: And just for your information : when you test locally (localhost:8080) it means you have the Server setup locally just for testing, Development and so on but actual server is somewhere else. I hope it helps.

Comment: I know the URL. Just don't know how to set it. Do i need to connect to the host for that? if yes, how?